# Можете объяснить что происходит во втрой строке? Не знаю такого синтаксиса

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
new_numbers =  [2 * x for x in numbers]
print(new_numbers)
```

Comment: Иногда не знаешь, что читать по конкретному месту, когда только начинаешь. Я, например, так и не понял, где посмотреть конструкцию super (ИмяКласса, self).__init__() Без "ИмяКласса, self" - масса примеров, а с ними - нет. Так что я понимаю Андрея.

Comment: @Сергей
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods

Comment: А, так это "you can just say super().__init__() instead of super(ChildB, self).__init__()". Спасибо! Но вот я не нашел, а в учебнике не оказалось (автор учебника дал новый синтаксис и старый пример).

Answer (score 4):

Это генератор списка. Создается список, аналогичный первому, но каждый элемент умножается на два. Вторая строка аналогична коду:

```
new_numbers = []
for x in numbers:
    new_numbers.append(2 * x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Новый список заполняется значением 2*x путём прохода по всему списку numbers.
Почитайте про генераторы и генераторные выражения.

Answer (score -1):

Это называется "Списковое включение" - компактная форма создания списка.
Иногда это быстрее чем через цикл for.

- после выхода из цикла for "переменная" x продолжает существовать, а после спискового включения она удаляется!

Ваш код генерирует список numbers умножив на 2 каждый элемент.